# Установка babel на Linux mint

Tags: node.js, babel

Помогите пожалуйста, при установке babel выдаёт такую ошибку

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /babel/chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9

я так понимаю "fsevents" относиться к OS X архитектуре, я не могу установить этот пакет npm так как у меня linux mint.

При запуске самого babel выдаёт такое :

```
fs.js:584  
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
               ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/medonomator/.babel.json'
  at Error (native)
  at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
  at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1224:33)
  at save (/home/medonomator/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/cache.js:35:19)
  at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:376:9)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:431:11)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
  at startup (node.js:142:18)
  at node.js:939:3
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, то что вы считаете *ошибками*, а именно:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /babel/chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9

*ошибками* не является. Это всего лишь *предупреждения*, о том, что npm не может установить *опциональную* зависимость.

Во-вторых, ваша проблема совсем не связана с этим пакетом. Вам же node не двусмысленно дает понять, что у него нет *полномочий на открытие* файла:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/medonomator/.babel.json'